# Use Yaml for MongoMapper Config

Tags: yaml, mongomapper

I have my Yaml configuration file, `mongo.yml`:

```
development:
  adapter: mongodb
  database: fhsclock_development
  host: localhost
  port: nil

test:
  adapter: mongodb
  database: fhsclock_test
  host: localhost
  port: nil

production:
  adapter: mongodb
  database: fhsclock
  hosts:
  - - localhost
    - nil
  - - staff.mongohq.com
    - 10015
```

How do I use this file for configuration and connection with MongoMapper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MongoMapper will just use the file if it's you're using Rails and the file is at `config/mongo.yml`.  If you're not on Rails, you can adapt [this code from the source](https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/blob/cbed744ce72b9395bd2da422c57f41e3284bf6c9/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie.rb#L23):

```
config_file = Rails.root.join('config/mongo.yml')
if config_file.file?
  config = YAML.load(ERB.new(config_file.read).result)
  MongoMapper.setup(config, Rails.env, :logger => Rails.logger)
end
```

Also, the "adapter" in your file is extraneous. (See the [Getting Started documentation](http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html)).  A `mongo.yml` from `rails g mongo_mapper:config` looks like:

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: my_app_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: my_app_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: my_app
  username: <%= ENV['MONGO_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGO_PASSWORD'] %>
```