# Can / should I change environment names in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

Doing a Rails project with MongoDB + MongoMapper

Rake creates the Mongo db with environment names hyphenated

ie myapp-development

which does not play well in the Mongo shell.... To edit the environment names, do I need to override the core Rails code or can it be done on a per app basis?

Else, is there a way to run commands normally on a hyphenated db name from mongo shell?

```
db.test.find()
```

returns OK

```
db.tests-hyphenated.find()
```

returns

```
ReferenceError: hyphenated is not defined
```

.

```
use tests-hyphenated
db.this.find()
```

returns OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it play in the mongo shell like this:

```
db["tests-hyphenated"].find()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **mongo.yml** to specify/change database environment information like database name and other related things...

Running following command will create **mongo.yml** inside **config** directory.

```
rails g mongo_mapper:config
```

Refer to answer of [Use Yaml for MongoMapper Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897319/use-yaml-for-mongomapper-config) to see example of mongo.yml file.

Comment: Thanks Amrish. The first answer got me out of trouble, but I will look at using your suggested method as the project continues.